# Arduino micros() implementation - code construction and SREG

Tags: c, arduino

EDIT: IGNORE question about ', t' bit... Please answer Q about SREG before cli()

I was just flicking through source and came across this in `wiring.c`:

```
unsigned long micros() {
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t; <<<<<<< What is the ', t' bit here?!

    cli();
    m = timer0_overflow_count;
    //etc
```

and I also wondered why the storing of SREG happens before cli().

Surely if an interrupt kicks in between the store of SREG and cli() there is a chance SREG could be changed resulting in loss of status when micros() restores its version of SREG (oldSREG)...

IGNORE: Predominantly I am interested in what `uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;` is doing.

Thanks for any feedback/help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;
```

is the same as:

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
uint8_t t;
```

It just declares an object `t` of type `uint8_t`.

**EDIT:** Question was edited, here is another answer:

If your function restores `SREG` at its end and if your interrupt handlers are accessing `SREG` then `oldSREG = SREG` should be put after `cli()` call to avoid any race condition.

Comment: Yep just 'facepalmed' self - I use this regularly... What about the SREG thing?

Comment: @PaulSullivan the declaration declares object `oldSREG` of type `uint8_t` and it read the value of `SREG` to initialize `oldSREG`.

Comment: I understand that it copies SREG into oldSREG but it is before cli(). If an interrupt cuts in, changes the status register and then passes control back to micros the oldSREG will not contain current SREG.

Comment: @PaulSullivan see my edit, next time you should open a new question.

Comment: ouah thanks for response (and yes I should have split this into two SO questions but you have answered both I believe). 

Just for clarity ouah the 'micros() code is not my own it is part of the core Arduino code and as I think you can see there is a race condition possible. 

Marking as answer and posting to arduino developers.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's just a short-hand way to declare multiple variables.

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;
```

is equivalent to:

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
uint8_t t;
```

Comment: Doh! Yes okay brain is farting... I use this regularly. What about the SREG thing?

Comment: Need a little more into on what CLI() does and what reg and oldreg are.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;
```

Is used to initialise multiple variables (oldSREG of SREG and t of default uint8_t)

It is the same as:

```
uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
uint8_t;
```

You could also write it as:

```
uint8_t t, oldSREG = SREG;
```

And would have the exact same effect

Comment: Yep I just realised my stupidity and tiredness... I use this regularly. What about the SREG store before cli()? Seems odd to me to store SREG while interrupts are still enabled